# How to display Validation Summary with Client side validation?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model:

```
namespace CameraWebApp.Models
{
    public class Images
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name")]
        public string SubmitterFirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your surname name")]
        public string SubmitterLastName { get; set; }
        [ExistingFileName]
        public string NameOfImage { get; set; }
        [StringLength(140, ErrorMessage="Please reduce the length of your description to below 140 characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string DescriptionOfImage { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Each property has some data annotations above them which I am using to validate server side and to display error messages in a validation summary, my view for which this is being used for is below:

```html
@model CameraWebApp.Models.Images
<video id="video">
</video>
<div id="main">
<h1>
    Instructions
</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Above: Live video stream from your computer's camera.</li>
    <li>Press "Camera button" (right in RED) until you are happy with the photo captured.</li>
    <li>Copy and paste the "big text string" into the address bar of your browser.</li>
    <li>What do you see?</li>
    <li>What applications can you imagine for this UI?</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="canvasHolder">
    <canvas id="hiddenCanvas">
    </canvas>
</div>
<div id="errorMessages">
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
</div>
<img id="preview" width="160" height="120" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/A/Y/O/m/o/N/placeholder-hi.png" alt="default portrait image">      
<!--<a id="button">Camera button</a>-->
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<label>base64 image:</label>
<input id="imageToForm" type="text" name="imgEncoded"/>  
<label>First Name</label>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubmitterFirstName)
<label>Last Name</label>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubmitterLastName)
<label>Name of Image</label>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameOfImage)
<label>Image Description</label>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DescriptionOfImage)
<input type=button id="button"value=" Camera button"/>
<input type="submit" value="Click this when your happy with your photo"/>
}
</div>
@Html.ActionLink("gfd!!", "DisplayLatest");

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/LiveVideoCapture.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The error messages displayed fine with the code above, my problem is I then tried to started to add client side validation and added the following code to my _Layout:

```html
<script src="http://localhost:55928/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:55928/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:55928/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:55928/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which does in fact validate on the client side as I can see from viewing the source but it does not display any error messages? Does anyone know A: Why is it no longer displaying my error messages? B: How can I display my error messages in a Validation summary when validating client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two validation summaries on the page - one outside the form, one inside. Client side validation will only write to summary containers *inside* forms (not sure if that's intentional or an oversight).

The one inside the form is made to exclude property level errors (the `true` argument) and only show model-wide errors.

Now, the `ValidationSummary` helper does this when generating the HTML (source modified to fit stackoverflow width):

```
if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // [snip]

    // TODO: This isn't really about unobtrusive; can we fix up 
    // non-unobtrusive to get rid of this, too?
    if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled 
        && excludePropertyErrors)
    {
       // No client-side updates
       return null;
    }
}
```

`excludePropertyErrors` is what you've set to `true`. If there are no errors on the ModelState when you return the HTML, and you've told it to exclude property errors, it won't output the validation summary container (`return null`) - because the client side validation only handles property errors, and you've told it you don't want those.

In short, two problems:

- client-side validation will not use the validation summary outside the form
- the validation summary inside the form will only be output if there's already been a validation error on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.YourProperty)` for all your properties